# HTML5 window.history doesn't run new javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have a page which shows some data from a database. 
Each of these data rows has a link with an ID.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="changeUrl(\'?side=annoncer&sletid='.$row['annonce_id'].'\');">
```

This is the `changeUrl` function:

```
function changeUrl(url) {
    window.history.replaceState(null, "Title", url);
}
```

The link points to the same page, with `&sletid` added.
When `&sletid` is set, the page should do a popup with the ID of the selected row.

```
if (isset($_GET['sletid'])) {
    $sletid = $_GET['sletid'];
    echo "<script language='JavaScript'>alert ('ID:".$sletid."');</script>";
}
```

The URL changes, and the popup script code is added to the source, but the popup doesn't show unless I manually update the page again. Why this behavior?

Comment: maybe you should use a `button` instead of `a`, if it's really not a link at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`replaceState` doesn't actually load the page, it just edits the history (and the location bar) in the browser.  You need to load the page yourself using AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

Your phpcode doesnt get executed because the change of the history state just affects the client side.
You need to listen to the change of the history on the client side.